# Create an interface that is a slice of another interface

Tags: go

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
type Model interface {
    EntityType() string
    GetKey() *datastore.Key
    SetKey(*datastore.Key) error
    PreSave(context.Context) error
    PostSave(context.Context) error
    PostLoad(context.Context) error
}

type Models []Model interface {
    Prepare(int) ([]Model, error)
}
```

So that the struct `Models` is also an interface and would get implemented by a slice of the structs that implement `Model`. Something like the following:

```
type Foo struct {
    key   *datastore.Key `datastore:"_"`
    // ... other things here
}

// assume all Model interface funcs are here and valid

type Foos []Foo

func (f *Foos) Prepare (num int) ([]Model, error) {
    // do the preparations for Foo slice
}
```

Obviously, the code above throws errors and isn't possible. But is there some code that would produce basically the same functionality? Without using `reflect` or anything costly like that?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  Please clarify what "this" in "Obviously, this isn't possible" means.

Comment: "this" meaning the code I have above threw errors for me. Question edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a simple

```
type Models interface {
    Prepare(int) ([]Model, error)
}
type Foos []Foo
func (f Foos) Prepare(num int) ([]Model, error) {
    // do the preparations for Foo slice
    return nil, nil
}
func main() {
    foos := Foos{}
    models := Models(foos)
    models.Prepare(17)
}
```

works.

So what is your actual question? Please see also https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types and https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface
Which should make it a bit clearer.

I would recommend to provide function (! not methods) to operate on `[]Model` and not to abstract the slice-of-model into some higher type.

Comment: I want to force the fact that `Foos` is a slice of `Model`. Not just it's own interface called `Models`. The slice is being passed into a function, where methods are being run on those elements in the slice that are on the `Model` interface. So I can't just create a new interface as it would not be a proper type hint for the function taking in the slice.

Comment: Thanks for answering, though. I've been looking over the code, and what I'm hoping to do just doesn't seem possible.